# Typescript compiler error for property that exists

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a `React` package called `react-canvas-draw`(https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw) and the main class `CanvasDraw` has a function called `getDataURL`. I know it does because I can see it in the code:

```
_defineProperty(_assertThisInitialized(_this), "getDataURL", function (fileType, useBgImage, backgroundColour)
```

The problem is that the type declaration doesn't have the function signature so my code doesn't see it as a function that can be called. This is in the `@types/react-canvas-draw/index.d.ts` file.

I've tried to manually edit the `index.d.ts` file to include the signature like so:
`getDataURL(fileType: string, useBgImage:boolean, backgroundColour:string): string;` and this does appease the editor so it accepts the method when I'm editing.

When I save, however, and it compiles it throws the following error:

```
Property 'getDataURL' does not exist on type 'CanvasDraw'
```

My code that is calling the method is from a `ref` that I know works because I have called other methods off the object, `undo()` for example. It is:

```
canvasDrawRef.getDataURL('png', false, '0xffffff');
```

Is there any way I can force this method to be called at runtime and prevent the compiler from throwing the error? And is there anything else I can do to declare the function as callable?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to quieten the compiler with the following line just above the code that I wanted it to ignore:
`// @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error`

I would only recommend doing this if you are sure the code is going to work.